# Error when connecting to xmpp

Tags: xmpp

02-18 01:53:29.980: ERROR/XMPPClient(350): [SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to gtalk.google.com
02-18 01:53:29.980: ERROR/XMPPClient(350): Could not connect to gtalk.google.com:5222.: remote-server-timeout(504) Could not connect to gtalk.google.com:5222.
02-18 01:53:29.980: ERROR/XMPPClient(350):   -- caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: gtalk.google.com
02-18 01:53:30.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(350): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 01:53:30.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(350): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to server.
02-18 01:53:30.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(350):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:329)
02-18 01:53:30.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(350):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:301)
02-18 01:53:30.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(350):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:283)
02-18 01:53:30.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(350):     at org.apache.android.xmpp.SettingsDialog.onClick(SettingsDialog.java:54)
02-18 01:53:30.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(350):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
02-18 01:53:30.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(350):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
02-18 01:53:30.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(350):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-18 01:53:30.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(350):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-18 01:53:30.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(350):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-18 01:53:30.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(350):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
02-18 01:53:30.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(350):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 01:53:30.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(350):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-18 01:53:30.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(350):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-18 01:53:30.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(350):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-18 01:53:30.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(350):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-18 01:53:35.710: ERROR/InputDispatcher(59): channel '4072b418 XMPP Settings (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
02-18 01:53:35.710: ERROR/InputDispatcher(59): channel '4072b418 XMPP Settings (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Comment: You're right, that is indeed an error.

Comment: I thought it was talk.google.com, not gtalk

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer about how to connect in the DNS:

```
$ dig +short -t SRV _xmpp-client._tcp.gmail.com.
20 0 5222 talk2.l.google.com.
20 0 5222 talk3.l.google.com.
20 0 5222 talk4.l.google.com.
5 0 5222 talk.l.google.com.
20 0 5222 talk1.l.google.com.
```

Where you replace `gmail.com` with the domain portion of the JID the client is trying to connect as.